# Enqueue javascript that inserts custom php widget into jQuery-constructed div

Tags: jquery, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

### What I need done:

The mobile menu on the site (let me know if you want to see the dev site, so I don't get marked as spam for posting the link) is loaded by a script that hides the main menu when the browser width falls below 1030px. Before then the mobile menu div doesn't exist. I have a shopping cart link on the desktop site that I'm trying to insert into that mobile menu div automatically whenever that div is generated by the script. Then I'll hide the one in the desktop code, etc.

I'm using the following to enqueue some jQuery, which in turn loads the custom "cart link" PHP plugin into a mobile menu div that is loaded by a separate js file only when the browser width is less than 1030px. Still with me? Here's the code:

### In functions.php:

```
function mobile_cart_script() {
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var pluginDir = <?php echo json_encode(bloginfo('url')); ?>;
  jQuery(".slicknav_menu").load(pluginDir+"/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce-cart-dropdown/cart-dropdown.php");
</script>

<?php

wp_register_script( 'mobile_cart_script', '', false, false, false );
wp_enqueue_script( 'mobile_cart_script' );

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','mobile_cart_script');
```

This isn't working.

I had first tried including the script right in the header, but the script required the mobile menu script to load before it. So I put the script in that file right after the script that calls the mobile menu, taking care of that dependancy. Then I discovered that this needed me to `require_once = wp-load.php` in the php plugin, which isn't ideal.

After searching around, I came across the `wp_enqueue_scripts` method above. It doesn't need the plugin to `require_once = wp-load.php`(I don't think), and it eliminates putting the code in `head` and overbearing the server, but it's still not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: Honestly, I think you are in the wrong direction; it seems that responsive CSS could do the job easier in this case. Anyway, note that wherever you put the javascript, you are loading a PHP file directly bypassing WordPress totally, so it dosen't matter where you put the javascript, the PHP script will needs to manually load WordPress anyway.

Comment: @cybmeta, yea I hear you on needing to load WP regardless of where I load the separate PHP file. Unfortunately, this is an existing site/mobile menu I'm trying to "hack" into, so as much as I'd rather use responsive CSS, it's not an option. That's why I'm asking on here. Any ideas?